# How can I import a native C++ static lib which uses boost::asio into a CLI/C++ mixed mode application?

Tags: c++, boost, c++-cli

I have a C++/CLI command line client and I'm trying to import a native C++ lib which in turn has `#include <boost/asio.hpp>`.

When I try to import this I get the following errors:

```
2>C:\boost_1_54_0\boost/asio/generic/detail/endpoint.hpp(27): error C2059: syntax error : 'generic'
2>C:\boost_1_54_0\boost/asio/generic/detail/endpoint.hpp(27): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
2>C:\boost_1_54_0\boost/asio/generic/detail/endpoint.hpp(27): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
2>C:\boost_1_54_0\boost/asio/generic/detail/impl/endpoint.ipp(32): error C2059: syntax error : 'generic'
```

The includes have to be in the static lib's header as they're member variables.

So what is the simplest option to import and use these classes from the static/native lib?

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate, as there's another question, with an answer that's slightly more succinct that should also fix this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27071560/how-to-use-boost-classes-in-a-net-ccli-gui-application?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has come up on the boost trac, you can find it [here](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/11855). The solution (courtesy of Michael Rasmussen) for the moment is to do this

```
#ifdef __cplusplus_cli
#define generic __identifier(generic)
#endif>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#ifdef __cplusplus_cli
#undef generic
#endif
```

and wrap your boost includes, that are having issues with the generic symbol in those ifdefs.

Edit: I missed the bit about your library being a static lib, you might want to use the dynamic boost library which can avoid issues with multiple symbols being defined. Use `BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK` preprocessor definition to use the boost dlls instead.

Comment: That does indeed appear to make the error messages go away. Nice one!